# Search on website with python and requests

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

The input from the search field:

```
<form class="search-form"     
action="http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/results#main-search" method="post">
<input class="text" placeholder="Search..." name="query" required="" type="search"> 
<input class="search-submit" value="Search" type="submit">
```

I have this script but it doesn't perform the search for me... Any idea why?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/'
body = {'Search':'rune'}
s = requests.Session()
log = s.get(url)
with requests.Session() as s:
    con = s.post('http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/results#main-search', data=body)
    print (con.text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two minor corrections and the code works for me:

```
import requests

body = {'query':'rune'} # <-- use 'query' not `Search'

con = requests.post('http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/results#main-search', data=body)
print (con.content) # <-- print .content not .text
```

Comment: Why define `url` if you don't use it?

Comment: @alfasin you have noo idea how much I thank you!! note: I am running a really strong computer but when I run scripts that load a page with a lot of data, my python turn white and do not answer. This said, do you think there would be a way to contact you if you have a second about requests module (that you seem to understand pretty well)

Comment: @Sait remains of the original script - good catch - cleaned it.

Comment: @Sait you are right, but I thought I had to create a get request first then make a post request with the 'new' url (if there is a new one)

Comment: @bob just post a question here - someone will pick it up ;)

Comment: @alfasin that is not true, I already asked similar questions... and I searched, trust me, for a week for how to login facebook with requests and no one really bothers trying to help, they usually say : 'oh try auth=(user,password) without the full code and it doesn't work. So if you have a minute, you really don't know how much and how long I wish to understand and make a script about login in a website and searching on one..

Comment: @alfasin So, would you mind helping me a bit more please? Again, it means a lot to me.

Comment: @bob of course, feel free to tag my name (in the comments) when you post a question

Comment: @alfasin did you see my facebook post that I tagged you on?

Comment: @alfasin here is the link to it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31496725/python3-how-would-i-log-in-facebook-using-requests