# Using POST to use built in search form on webpage

Tags: python, html

I'm fairly new to Python, and this is my first post to stackoverflow, and as a starting project I'm trying to write a program that will gather the prices of board games from different websites that sell them. As part of this I'm trying to write a function that will use a website's built-in search function to find the webpage I want for a game that I input.

The code I'm using so far is:

```
    import requests

    body = {'keywords':'galaxy trucker'}
    con = requests.post('http://www.thirstymeeples.co.uk/', data=body)

    print(con.content)
```

My problem is that the webpage it returns is not the webpage I get when I manually input and search for 'galaxy trucker' on the website itself.

The html for the search form in question is

> ```
>    <form method="post" action="http://www.thirstymeeples.co.uk/">
>     <input type="search" name="keywords" id="keywords" class="searchinput" value>
>    </form>
> ```

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31443903/search-on-website-with-python-and-requests) but with that the difference to me seems to be that the search actually appears on the webpage, whereas with mine, the web address provided in the action section does not itself display a search bar. In this example too, there is no id keyword in the html, whereas in mine there is, does this make a difference?

Comment: I see no search form on that page...

Answer (score 0):

No search form on the index page, but if you do a "manual" search from the "games" page (which does hae a form), you end up on a page with this url:

> http://www.thirstymeeples.co.uk/games/search/q?collection=search_games|search_designers|search_publishers&loose_ends=right&search_mode=all&keywords=galaxy+trucker

Notice that this page does take GET params, and that if you change the `keywords` from "galaxy+trucker" to anything else you get an updated result page. IOW, you want to do a GET request at http://www.thirstymeeples.co.uk/games/search/q:

```
r = requests.get("http://www.thirstymeeples.co.uk/games/search/q", params={"keywords": "galaxy trucker"})
print(r.content)
```